# Configure Flutter SDK in android studio

Tags: android, flutter

Configured flutter in Android studio. Path for SDK was c:/src/flutter/flutter.. where I have extracted flutter files. Still when I run app Android studio says flutter SDK not configured. What should I do? Already installed flutter plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try running **flutter doctor** in command prompt/terminal. It looks like you didn't add the flutter SDK path to the environment variables.
For more help [visit flutter website](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows).

Comment: I did that.. c:/src/flutter/flutter/bin

Comment: It will be better if you could add the screenshot.